# IE SyntaxError: Expected '}' in JSON parsing from Java

Tags: java, angularjs, json, gson

I have a problem in one of my projects.

We have a backend in Java and a FrondEnd app in HTML and AngularJS (v1.4.6).

In the frondend we display a table contaning some records retrieved from Java in JSON format.

In Java we use GSON to convert an object to JSON format and then we will send to browser.
Here's my Java Code:

```
public class doSomething {
    public void caricaFile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FiltriParameters filtri) throws IOException 
    {
        RetObj r = caricaFile(request, response, filtri, ...);
        response.getWriter().println(Utils.json(r));
    }
}

public class Utils {
    public final static String json(Object obj) {
        return new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create().toJson(obj);
    }
}
```

Here's our Angular Function

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(files) {
    if (files.length == 0)
        return;

    openLoader();
    var fd = new FormData();
    //Take the first selected file
    fd.append("file", files[0]);

    $http.post(urlUploader, fd, {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
        transformRequest: angular.identity
    })
    .success(function(response){
        closeLoader();
        response = angular.fromJson(response);
        // do something
    })
    .error(
        function(response){
            closeLoader();
            alert(response);
        });

    $( "#file-upload" ).val("");
}
```

In chrome everything works fine, the JSON get received then parsed and all the rows are showed in the html table.

In Internet Explorer we get the following error. "response is undefined" in `error` function

IE Console:

```
SyntaxError: Expected '}'
   at uc (http://127.0.0.1:8085/HERMESCS2/js/generics/1-4-6angular.min.js?vid=120:15:463)
   at Zb (http://127.0.0.1:8085/HERMESCS2/js/generics/1-4-6angular.min.js?vid=120:82:227)
   at Anonymous function (http://127.0.0.1:8085/HERMESCS2/js/generics/1-4-6angular.min.js?vid=120:83:141)
   at m (http://127.0.0.1:8085/HERMESCS2/js/generics/1-4-6angular.min.js?vid=120:7:320)
   at cd (http://127.0.0.1:8085/HERMESCS2/js/generics/1-4-6angular.min.js?vid=120:83:125)
   at d (http://127.0.0.1:8085/HERMESCS2/js/generics/1-4-6angular.min.js?vid=120:84:366)
   at Anonymous function (http://127.0.0.1:8085/HERMESCS2/js/generics/1-4-6angular.min.js?vid=120:118:324)
   at n.prototype.$eval (http://127.0.0.1:8085/HERMESCS2/js/generics/1-4-6angular.min.js?vid=120:132:441)
   at n.prototype.$digest (http://127.0.0.1:8085/HERMESCS2/js/generics/1-4-6angular.min.js?vid=120:129:455)
   at n.prototype.$apply (http://127.0.0.1:8085/HERMESCS2/js/generics/1-4-6angular.min.js?vid=120:133:234)
```

Here a pastebin with the JSON the backend returns to frontend/angular.
https://pastebin.com/zUiX3AtV

We already tested it and it's a valid JSON

Any Advice?

Comment: The JSON appears to be valid.

Comment: It could be a simple syntax error in your JS, check beyond this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved

I changed the `content-type` in the header response to: `text/json` somehow Internet Explorer is affected by this whereas Chrome/FireFox no!

```
public class doSomething {
    public void caricaFile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FiltriParameters filtri) throws IOException 
    {
        RetObj r = caricaFile(request, response, filtri, ...);
        response.setContentType("text/json");
        response.getWriter().println(Utils.json(r));
    }
}
```